# Question about intents for different elements in Android

Tags: android, android-intent, mobile, android-activity

I want to code an app that has a `Listview` that shows 3d solids list. From the list, I can select a 3d solid. Then my task is to open new activity with Intent, based on what kind of solid is selected - for every solid new activity.
Therefore I would like to ask how can this be accomplished given the fact that I try to do this by changing the positions of the selected element.

```
private void setUpOnclickListener()
    {
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l)
            {
                Solid selectSolid = (Solid) (listView.getItemAtPosition(position));
                switch(position){
                    case 0:
                        Intent showDetail = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DetailActivityCylinder.class);
                        startActivity(showDetail);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        Intent showDetail2 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DetailActivityCone.class);
                        startActivity(showDetail2);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        Intent showDetail3 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DetailActivityCuttedCone.class);
                        startActivity(showDetail3);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        Intent showDetail4 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DetailActivitySphere.class);
                        startActivity(showDetail4);
                        break;
                }

            }
        });

    }
```

[image]

Comment: use recycler view rather than using listview

Comment: what is in Solid.java ?

Answer (score 0):

In `switch case` use `selectSolid` object instead of position to identify which solid is selected then based on selection open respective activity. Try to use enum to define solid type.